# scrollIntoView({behaviour: "smooth"}) doesn't work on brave, chromium But works on Firefox (REACT JS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, smooth-scrolling

As said in title

```
this.myreference.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

doesn't work in chromium or brave

CSS for `html { scroll-behaviour: smooth ; }` does nothing either

Are there any alternatives to achieve a similar effect?

I'm looking to scroll to the next screenwide div on mousewheel,
Something like this

```
-> <div>Covers entire Screen</div>
   <div>Covers entire Screen</div>
```

*user mouse wheels*

```
   <div>Covers entire Screen</div>
-> <div>Covers entire Screen</div>
```

Thank You :)

```
[As said in title, using react]
```

Edit: I know it works without { behavior: "smooth" } but it's sharp

Comment: `scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })` is currently working on Firefox, Chromium and Brave. In Chromium browsers, but with the default scrolling rules for these last two, if you set the flag `#smooth-scrolling` (in Brave) to disabled, the browser will enforce this behavior and will prevent the smooth scrolling in any document.